# What is the Irish myth of the maiden seduced for one day by the foreign king?

Tags: irish

There is an Irish quasi-historical myth in which a foreign king comes by the sea and lands in Ireland where he encounters a princess and they dally for one afternoon and he tells her, "You shall be born of a king" and he gives her his ring as a momento and tells her to give the ring to her child if it should be a son, then departs. Eventually she gives birth to an important king. What is this myth?

In the story the princess rejects many suitors, but when she meets the strange prince from the sea, he says to her "Shall we have an hour of lovemaking?" and she agrees and asks "How is that all the princes of my land have asked for my hand in marriage, but you possess me so?" Immediately after the encounter he departs so they are together only for an afternoon.

Note that in the Irish histories, this story is represented as a true story and the descendants of this supposed union are actual high kings of Ireland.

Comment: More details are needed. What are some elements that you are pretty sure about? Are you sure there is a ring? Are you sure it is Irish or could also be from somewhere in Great Britain?

Comment: @Mauricio It is absolutely from Irish history. The ring is an essential part of the story because the mother gives to the infant who later becomes an important king and the ring proves who his sire/lineage is.

Comment: Sounds like a mix between Uther Pendragon, Gráinne and Diarmuid, and Sigfried. In what format did you read it? A book? Oral tradition? Video?